# why is the dark mode transition covering the whole text?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]Im facing a problem with a transition from light mode to dark mode. In JavaScript after the `else` the variables cover all of my HTML text that is inside a flexbox and not the body (i think that this might be the problem but I dont know how to solve it.

**JavaScript**

```
const toggle = document.getElementById('toggleDark');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('bi-moon');
    if(this.classList.toggle('bi-brightness-high-fill')){
        body.style.background = 'white';
        body.style.color = 'black';
        body.style.transition = '2s';
    }else{
        body.style.background = 'black';
        body.style.color = 'white';
        body.style.transition = '2s';
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>home site</title> 
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
</head>

<body>

  
</body>
    
<div class="top-container">
  <span class="scrittaSu"><h1><span class="greg">GREG'S</span> PORTFOLIO</h1></span>
  <span class="scrittaGiu"><p>Home.</p></span>
</div>


<header> 
        <span><li><a class="active" href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html" target="_blank">HOME</a><li></span>
        <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/portfolio.html" target="_blank" font="arial" >PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/aboutme.html" target="_blank" >ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <i class="bi bi-brightness-high-fill" id="toggleDark"></i>
        </header>


        
    <div class="flex-container"> <!--beijvbihvbsdakjvbalksjvb-->
      <div class="flex-left">
        <span class="contentTop"><h2>random text</h2><span><br>
          <span class="contentBottom"><p>random text
             <br>
         random text
```

[image]

I expected the whole text to transfer into darkmode, but just the background did. I think its because the text isnt included in `body.style.color = 'white';`.

Really dont know wha to do. thank you

Comment: Only elements that do not define `color` by themselves, or inherit from a closer ancestor, will inherit the color of the text from the body.

Comment: @connexo so i should remove the color attributes that define the color of text in the flexbox to make it work?

Comment: Rather use the approach suggested as an answer.

Comment: @connexo should the whole text from header to footer be inside the <body><body>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a better way to add dark/light modes to your website, for example:

> Add in CSS

```
    :root {
  --background: #f2f2f2;
  --card: #bfbfbf;
  --card-hover: #22303c;
  --secondary-card-hover: #1c3142;
  --main-text-color: #000;
  --secondary-text-color: #8899a6;
  --link-hover: #fd8f8f;
}
.dark-theme {
  --background: #15202b;
  --card: #192734;
  --card-hover: #22303c;
  --secondary-card-hover: #22303c;
  --secondary-text-color: #8899a6;
  --main-text-color: #fff;
  --link-hover: #2a9ec9;
}
```

> js:

```
const themeIcon = document.querySelector(".header nav .fa-regular"); 
themeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
   document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
   //add code here to change themIcon in each mode
})
```

Comment: Please add an explanation, as OP is obviously not very experienced.

Comment: Copied the exact code but now when i click on the icon nothing happens

Comment: no the code I wrote is just an example, I wanted to show you the idea and you have to replace what needs to be replaced

Comment: @AyanoQ mb im new to JS and coding in general. Should the whole html text be inside the <body> element? Because I put everything outside of it

Answer (score 0):

> every html file is like this

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

> and every html element that appears in your website should be in body tag
> now you can fix your code by yourself!

Comment: Hey! So I’ve fixed the html apparently, but still don’t know how to deal with the JS. Do you have any tutorial that explains this part of JS? I would like to understand what’s actually going on with the code you shared. Thank you so much

Comment: before sharing the tutorial, I advice you to look for **CSS variables** and **JS basics**, here is the link of youtube video:  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LZGB3OLXNQ), good luck